# Who was the shooter?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

**Follow the numbers to answer the question:**

**Number A:** The order of Romeos passenger in the Greek alphabet.

**Number B:** The two last digits in the year the returning Lex Luthor was awarded his (number A) Oscar.

**Number C:** The man in B didn't manage to complete in this city on time, and could have called in his complaint on this number, in *Apple time*!

**Number D:** The number of the street in the city of C where marble is buried.

**Number E:** A *European convention* was held in a city in Italy sometime in the 20th century, and they discussed a partial golden retreat. In March 2007 the football club from the same city was in the (number D) league of the country. The two last digits of the year before, and the two last digits of the year after the conference is the number of this clue.

**Number F:** In the episode (number E) of Sesame Street, Kermit the frog appears this number of times.

*Who was the shooter?*

Comment: Clue E seems a bit weird: "this convention" (is that the same as "the conference"?), "this city", and "the number of this clue" - so are we supposed to get a convention, a city, or a number as the answer?

Comment: @randal'thor I have refined clue E now, so it should be clear that it is a number I am looking for...

Comment: Thanks for the street edit! I think I'm on the right track then. Also for the edit to E :-)

Comment: I edited in the word 'number' several places, to clarify even further.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm borrowing heavily from the other answers, but I'm putting everything into one place.

> A: The order of Romeos passenger in the Greek alphabet.

The answer is

> 1,

because

> Alfa Romeo is a car manufacturer; cars have passengers, and alpha is the 1st letter of the Greek alphabet, associated with Romeo.

Thank you to @rand-althor.

**Second clue**

> B: The two last digits in the year the returning Lex Luthor was awarded his (number of clue A) Oscar.

The answer is

> 96,

because

> Kevin Spacey played Lex Luthor in *Superman Returns* and was awarded his 1st Oscar for his appearance in The Usual Suspects in 1995. He was awarded this Oscar in 1996.

Thank you to @rand-althor and @dmg.

**Third clue**

> C. The man in B didn't manage to complete here on time, and could have called in his complaint on this number, in *Apple time!*

The answer is

> 311

We've identified *The man in B* as Kevin Spacey, who attended the Juilliard School in New York City to become a comedian, but left before receiving a diploma.

> If you have a complaint in NYC, you can dial 3-1-1.

Thank you, @CDSpace.

**Fourth clue**

> D. The street in the city of C where marble is buried.

We've identified the city of C to be New York City, so the answer is

> 2

because of the [marble cemetery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City_Marble_Cemetery) located on

> 2nd Street.

Thank you, @rand-althor.

**Fifth clue**

> E. A European convention was held in a city in Italy sometime in the 20th century, and they discussed a partial golden retreat. In March 2007 the football club from the same city was in the (number of clue D) league. The two last digits of the year before, and the two last digits of the year after the conference is the number of this clue.

The answer is:

> 21 and 23

because

> The Genoa Conference was held (in Genoa) between representatives of 34 countries in 1922 to discuss the global economic situation following World War I. Genoa CFC played in the 2006/2007 Italian Cup, Serie B.

**Sixth clue**

> F. In the episode number (E) of Sesame Street, Kermit the frog appears this number of times.

The answer is

> 0

because

> Kermit made no appearances in episode 2123 of Sesame Street.

Put these clues together and you have a date and time.

> 1 + 96 + 311 + 2 + 21 + 23 + 0 → 1963-11-22 12:30
>  It was at 12:30 CST, November 22, 1963, when President John F. Kennedy was shot twice by **Lee Harvey Oswald**.

Comment: I am impressed. You are so close, but still have some faults. Where is the number of C? And also, I suggest you read B carefully to see the wording...

Comment: I see a comment from @CDSpace that I'll try to incorporate.

Comment: @Enigma I think I've got it now...

Comment: @PaulRowe I think so too. Congrats!

Comment: Congratulations. However, I am not sure who the shooter actually was...:-) The italics are a reference to the date and time, in European date convention, and New York Time.

Comment: Golden retreat is a reference to the discussion on the Genoa conference to go back to the practice of the gold standard, that you could always exchange money with gold.

Comment: It's actually ISO 9601 complete date plus hours and minutes (less time zone). After sleeping on this, I realized what you meant by the wording in B and the rest of it fell into place. Knowing the year of the convention made finding the convention simple; I didn't pay a lot of attention to the agenda of the convention. I'll look at that now, though, as it interests me.

Comment: @PaulRowe Again, congratulations! I am really impressed. I hope you enjoyed it:-)

Comment: @Enigma It was quite fun, thanks! I couldn't have done it without all the help from other contributors.

Answer (score 4):

**First clue**

> A: The order of Romeos passenger in the Greek alphabet.

The answer is

> 1,

because

> Alfa Romeo is a car manufacturer; cars have passengers, and alpha is the 1st letter of the Greek alphabet, associated with Romeo.

**Second clue**

> B: The two last digits in the year the returning Lex Luthor was awarded his (number of clue A) Oscar.

The answer is

> <s>99</s> 95,

because

> Kevin Spacey played Lex Luthor in *Superman Returns*, and won his 1st Oscar in <s>1999</s> 1995 (**thanks @dmg!**).

**Third and fourth clues**

> C. The man in B didn't manage to complete here on time, and could have called in his complaint on this number, in *Apple time!*
>
> D. The street in the city of C where marble is buried.

Since C is a city, the reference to apples makes me think it's

> New York,

giving the answer to D as

> 2nd Street, because of the [marble cemetery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City_Marble_Cemetery) located there.

**Fifth clue**

> E. A European convention was held in a city in Italy sometime in the 20th century, and they discussed a partial golden retreat. In March 2007 the football club from the same city was in the (number of clue D) league. The two last digits of the year before, and the two last digits of the year after the conference is the number of this clue.

I know almost nothing of football, but [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006%E2%80%9307_UEFA_Champions_League) tells me that

> the only Italian football club in the 2nd league in 2006-07 was from Milan.

I've come up with 2 possibilities for a *European convention* being held there in the 20th century. Firstly:

> the European Population Conference on 4-8 September 1995. Footnote 11 on page 322 [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=IhwkBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA322&lpg=PA322&dq=20th-century+european+conference+in+milan&source=bl&ots=a1aqg0Sxly&sig=LTZENXiyOHXgBYXvScCOKg01e3M&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tHf9VNX4Lcj8UOOWhNgL&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=20th-century%20european%20conference%20in%20milan&f=false) mentions European mass migration in the 20th century - maybe this could be seen as a "partial golden retreat"? The catch is that there aren't **9496** episodes in Sesame Street!

Secondly:

> [the International Conference on Unemployment in 1906](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2339981?sid=21105581956251&uid=3738032&uid=2&uid=2129&uid=70&uid=4), which would give the number **507**. The catch is that I can't see how this fits "partial golden retreat".

**Sixth clue**

> F. In the episode number (E) of Sesame Street, Kermit the frog appears this number of times.

I need to resolve the fifth clue for this to be any use!

**Final answer**:

> We have **1st**, **99**, **New York**, **2nd Street**, ???, ???. Given the title of the question, I suspect the answer may have to do with a shooting on 2nd Street in New York, possibly on a date given by the numbers in the other clues.

Comment: I don't think it is even possible to solve this, without solving ALL clues correctly. You are not there yet, but keep working!

Comment: @Enigma So the final answer is wrong? Have I got A-D correct at least? My (non-)knowledge of football and TV is going to let me down in E-F :-(

Comment: Your final answer is far off, sorry... All clues are connected, so if one gets wrong, the others won't fit. So no comment on how the clues are interpreted, sorry!

Comment: @Enigma I think I've got quite a bit further now. Still no hints? :-)

Comment: I think it could be a good advice to look into the exact wording of clue C again..:-)

Comment: @randal'thor Kevin Spacey won his first Oscar in 1995 for [The Usual Suspects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academy_Award_for_Best_Supporting_Actor#1990s)

Comment: @randal'thor Not wanting to overstep my bounds here, but the _European convention_ part kinda smells like WW2 to me. Perhaps some partial retreat of Italy or the Axis from the "golden sands" of Sahara? (btw if I'm annoying you, say the word and I'll stop).

Comment: @dmg You're not annoying me at all! :-) I'm struggling here with very little knowledge of football, TV, or films. If you help me out enough, we can community-wikify the answer! I thought of WW2 too, but couldn't find any convention held in Milan.

Comment: @randal'thor This is quite interesting. According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006%E2%80%9307_UEFA_Cup#Italian_match-fixing_scandal) there was some drama regarding Italian clubs and the UEFA Cup (the secondary league). Which is why in 2006-2007 lesser known clubs participated (Chievo, Parma, Palermo and Livorno). And, all of them are knocked out before March...

Comment: @randal'thor Oh, and BTW the UEFA Championship is the Premier (first) league, so that is why I'm suggesting the UEFA Cup (second league). Or the "2", should be a "1".

Comment: In looking for episodes of Sesame Street which mention Kermit, I found 406 (Season 4, Episode 1), 810 (Season 7, Episode 15), 911 (Season 7, Episode 116), 1012 (Season 8, Episode 77), and 1214 (Season 10, Episode 29). This should help narrow down the date of the convention.

Comment: @dmg Thanks for the info re. 1st/2nd leagues! But according to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006–07_UEFA_Cup#Round_of_16), all the Italian teams were out of the UEFA Cup by March 2007. This is *puzzling*...

Comment: @PaulRowe Apparently Kermit was not featured in Sesame Street since 2001 up to November 10, 2009 due to some rights issues. That is why I'm inclined to think that the answer may be zero. Seeing that there are 4378 episodes of Sesame Streets, and assuming that the last few hundred don't feature Kermit it would fit with the WW2 suggestion (39-41, 40-42, 41-43, etc.)

Comment: I was hoping to be able to figure out the clues by guessing the answer. The first four digits you have form a year and the remaining clues could generate a date, such as 1/3, 1/30, 1/31, 2/4, .... I can't find any notable assassinations, so it may be a different use of "shooter".

Comment: @PaulRowe +1 for your reasoning... You are on the right track...:-)

Comment: [This article](http://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=SFC19020607.2.3#) mentions a 1902 meeting between America and the See in Rome discussing land in the Phillipines. If the convention in the clue was in 1902, then we're looking at episode 103 and Kermit made zero appearances in that episode.

Comment: Note that for (C), [complaints](http://www1.nyc.gov/311/index.page) to the city can be called in on the phone number 311

Answer (score 0):

A: The order of Romeos passenger in the Greek alphabet.

> 1st. As @Rand said, "Alfa Romeo is a car manufacturer; cars have passengers, and alpha is the 1st letter of the Greek alphabet, associated with Romeo."

B: The two last digits in the year the returning Lex Luthor was awarded his (number of clue A) Oscar.

> 95. Since Kevin Spacey played who played Lex Luthor in Superman Returns won his 1st Oscar in 1995 for bets supporting actor for his role in Pulpe Fiction.

C. The man in B didn't manage to complete here on time, and could have called in his complaint on this number, in Apple time!

> Microsoft. Since I think it's something related with the "suit by Apple accused Microsoft, along with Intel and the San Francisco Canyon Company, in 1995 of knowingly stealing several thousand lines of QuickTime source code in an effort to improve the performance of Video for Windows."

D. The street in the city of C where marble is buried.

> 65th street Redmond. Redmond is the city in Washington where Microsoft resides. Then if you search for marbles or granite you will know that all the marble companies or service providers in Redmond are there.

E. A European convention was held in a city in Italy sometime in the 20th century, and they discussed a partial golden retreat. In March 2007 the football club from the same city was in the (number of clue D) league. The two last digits of the year before, and the two last digits of the year after the conference is the number of this clue.

> 13,15. Organo Gold Europe convention was held in 2014 on Rome, Italy. AS ROMA a football team from Rome played against OL which was playing its 65th champions league match.

F. In the episode number (E) of Sesame Street, Kermit the frog appears this number of times.

> Yet to find the solution for this clue.

Comment: 2014 isn't in the 20th century, so clue E is probably wrong.

Comment: Who was the shooter...?